# Unable to save Test Kitchen kitchen.yml file on Windows 10

Tags: chef-infra, windows-10, atom-editor

I just created a new cookbook and I'm trying to test it in Test Kitchen. I'm following the [get started with test-kitchen guide](https://learn.chef.io/local-development/rhel/get-started-with-test-kitchen/).

This workflow works fine on Ubuntu but if I try it on my Windows 10 system my Atom editor does not allow be to save the `.kitchen.yml` file. Atom gives me the following error:

```
Unable to save file '\workstation\Boxcryptor\Box.net\Devel\chef-repo\cookbooks\motd_rhel.kitchen.yml'
EPERM: operation not permitted, open '\\workstation\Boxcryptor\Box.net\Devel\chef-repo\cookbooks\motd_rhel\.kitchen.yml'
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: can you save other files there? can you save files with a leading `.` in the file name?

Comment: Yes I can save either a "normal" file or one that begins with a "."

Comment: Check that you don't have something already there with a write-protect bit or similar?